# Sync vs Async in DFP

Tags: google-dfp

I haven't signed up for DFP Premium yet, but I had a question about it.

If I choose to use asynchronous DFP tags on my site, what happens if my site loads a line item for an advertiser that only has synchronous tags? Will the DFP placement still load asynchronously? Will DFP try to 'convert' a sync tag to an async one? (I have heard of other adservers doing this...). Also, what happens if the advertiser tag contains document.write().... will it still work to put that advertiser in an asynchronous DFP setup?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use sync ad tags in an async DFP setup. DFP loads the ad tags in an iframe and the tags can run document.write() all they want.

There are some drawbacks though. The iframes have a fixed size. If the sync tag renders a smaller creative, or no creative at all, then the ad unit still takes up the full size. You can work around this but that's kind of a nuisance, especially because the collapseEmptyDivs() method doesn't know if a third party tag has delivered a creative or not.

Besides that you'll have problems with out of page creatives if they don't check if they are being rendered in an iframe. The DFP iframes are 'friendly iframes' by default, so it's extremely easy to escape them for a creative, but the creative does need some small modifications for this to work.

But you can test all of this by trying the Small Business version of DFP. It's the exact same product with some advanced features (mostly related to targeting) disabled. Ad delivery is exactly the same when it comes to sync vs async.

Comment: Bart--regarding "ad delivery is exactly the same for sync vs async"... it used to be async only let the first tag see the on-page content, but passback tags weren't able to, leading to lower bids from exchanges served via passback in async DFP tags. Sync DFP tags OTOH let passbacks still access on-page content resulting in higher passback bids. Is this no longer the case?

Comment: Also, curious whether this means that a) passbacks in Async tags can now access on-page content when bidding, or b) passbacks in Sync tags now can *not* access on-page content when bidding??

Comment: Because of issues like that I tend to avoid passbacks like the plague... AFAIK a creative that's delivered through a passback will be able to access the content (with some work). I don't know about the information that's available during bidding. I do know that the whole RTB/advertising eco-system is far from transparent, let alone well documented...

Comment: "You can use sync ad tags in an async DFP setup" - How?

Comment: By including them in your DFP creative. They will be executed but not in a truly synchronous way in the page context. It will only be synchronous inside the iframe but the iframe itself is asynchronously loaded.